# Downvote on every Answer I've made

Tags: support, down-votes

Is there any automation thats downvotes every answer I gave? Or could it be that somebody doesn't like me? What could I do against it?

Comment: Someone is upset..., no, and at the end of the the UTC day a script will run and reverse serial downvotes (and upvotes).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Somebody took offense at something you said or did, and is being a baby about it.  It happens to everyone.  The serial downvoting gets reversed at the end of the day, so don't worry about it or let it get you down.  (I just got serial downvoted again, too... must be one of those days)

Comment: @LBT Same thing will happen if someone really likes what you did and they serial upvote you.  No one ever complains about serial upvoting but will still be reversed.

Comment: @bluefeet - oh, they'll complain afterwards alright, but not during :)